# Convert a tuple vector into a matrix in Julia

Tags: matrix, tuples, julia

Let's suppose we have a function, that gives us following:

```
julia> ExampleFunction(Number1, Number2)
5-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (2, 2)
 (2, 3)
 (3, 3)
 (3, 2)
 (4, 2)
```

I would like to convert `Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}`
into a matrix, or in my case I would like to convert it into a 5x2 Matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from your question how the 5-element vector of tuples of length 2, which has 10 elements in total, should be converted to a 3x2 matrix which holds 6 elements, but assuming that you meant 5x2 here's one way of doing it:

```
julia> x = [(1,2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
3-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (1, 2)
 (2, 3)
 (3, 4)

julia> hcat(first.(x), last.(x))
3×2 Matrix{Int64}:
 1  2
 2  3
 3  4
```

EDIT: As Phips mentioned an alternative below, here's a quick benchmark on Julia 1.7beta3, Windows 10 - I've thrown in a loop version as well, as it always makes sense to try a straightforward loop in Julia:

```
julia> convert_to_tuple1(x) = hcat(first.(x), last.(x))
convert_to_tuple1 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> convert_to_tuple2(x) = PermutedDimsArray(reshape(foldl(append!, x, init = Int[]), 2, :), (2, 1))
convert_to_tuple2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> function convert_to_tuple3(x)
           out = Matrix{eltype(x[1])}(undef, length(x), length(x[1]))
           for i ∈ 1:length(x)
               for j ∈ 1:length(x[1])
                   out[i, j] = x[i][j]
               end
           end
           out
       end
convert_to_tuple3 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> xs = [(rand(1:10), rand(1:10)) for _ ∈ 1:1_000_000];

julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> @btime convert_to_tuple1($xs);
  15.789 ms (6 allocations: 30.52 MiB)

julia> @btime convert_to_tuple2($xs);
  22.067 ms (21 allocations: 18.91 MiB)

julia> @btime convert_to_tuple3($xs);
  7.286 ms (2 allocations: 15.26 MiB)
```

(further edited to add `$` for interpolation of `xs` into the benchmark)

Comment: A variant with (I think) fewer allocations: `PermutedDimsArray(reshape(foldl(append!, x, init=Int[]), 2, :), (2, 1))`.

Comment: You forgot `$` in benchamrking - that should be `@btime convert_to_tuple1($xs);`

Comment: Indeed - although it doesn't seem to make any difference in my benchmarks here. Still good practice and I shouldn't be posting examples of benchmarking on SO that omit this, so thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 4):

The fastest code would be a non-copying one. In example from the other post this would reduce times from milliseconds to nanoseconds:

```
julia> xs
1000000-element Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}:
 (5, 1)
 (4, 3)
 ⋮
 (1, 4)
 (9, 2)

julia> @btime reshape(reinterpret(Int, $xs), (2,:))'
  10.611 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)
1000000×2 adjoint(reshape(reinterpret(Int64, ::Vector{Tuple{Int64, Int64}}), 2, 1000000)) with eltype Int64:
  5   1
  4   3
  ⋮
  1   4
  9   2
```

And for the copying code the fastest is going to be:

```
function convert_to_tuple4(x)
   out = Matrix{eltype(x[1])}(undef, length(x), length(x[1]))
   for i ∈ 1:length(x)
         @inbounds @simd for j ∈ 1:length(x[1])
             out[i, j] = x[i][j]
         end
   end
   out
end
```

Benchmarks:

```
julia> @btime convert_to_tuple3($xs);
  3.488 ms (2 allocations: 15.26 MiB)

julia> @btime convert_to_tuple4($xs);
  2.932 ms (2 allocations: 15.26 MiB)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# Example tuple
tuple_data = ((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9))

# Convert tuple into a matrix
matrix_data = reshape(collect(Iterators.flatten(tuple_data)), length(tuple_data), length(tuple_data[1]))

# Print the resulting matrix
println(matrix_data)
```

The function `Iterators.flatten(tuple_data)` is used to flatten the tuple into a 1D
iterator, and the `collect` function is then applied to convert the 1D iterator into an array. Then using the `reshape` function to reshape the array into a matrix with the desired dimensions, specified by `length(tuple_data)` and `length(tuple_data[1])`, and you will the matrix you want.